# What are the different approaches for transforming XML with Java?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, groovy, transformation

I´m researching how to transform XML from one format to another in a Java project.

What alternatives are there and what are their pros and cons?

Alternatives I´ve found so far:

1. XSLT/XQuery
2. XML-binding both formats to Java and do the mapping in Java
3. Groovy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're transforming XML to XML, then you'll only make extra work for yourself if you go via a non-XML representation (such as Java objects). Using a high-level declarative language is the way to go, and that means XSLT or XQuery.

In choosing between XSLT and XQuery, my usual advice is that XSLT is optimized for transformation and XQuery is optimized for query. By "transformation" I mean tasks in which most of the input appears in the output, just in a different form. By "query" I mean extracting nuggets of information from a sea of data.

Of course, all these technologies have a learning curve, and if you have a small one-off job to do, then that can be a valid factor in choosing your tools. But the best advice for a project doing XML and Java is to do as little Java as possible. Thinking about it as "a Java project" is probably a bad starting position.

Answer (score 6):

I vote for `XSLT`. It has the strong advantage that the transformation rules are separated from your java code. So later on, you can easily react to schema changes without touching your code.

*And* you can test/debug the transformation anywhere - no need to run the application.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say also:

1. [SAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPSAX2.html#wp72451) can be simpler to implement is your transformation is straightforward enough
2. XSLT if your transformation or data structure is complex, use schemas and will need a solid base for maintainability

Another option is [JDOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPDOM2.html#wp67733) but only if you have a simple, object-like data structure and don't want to use schemas.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that the defacto standard is XSLT. I personally hate XSLT for it's verbosity and find it difficult to read and maintain.

I much prefer freemarker and I've found that java developers find it much easier to pick up and maintain. Freemarker has built in [XML support](http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui_imperative_learn.html) including [xpath](http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui_imperative_learn.html#autoid_72). You can create custom freemarker tags for common tasks to further improve reuse and readability and reduce verbosity.

One of the things I love about freemarker is that you can inject java helpers and services into the freemarker context and you can invoke methods in your templates. These methods can hit your database for example. To do this in XSLT we used to convert db tables to XML and then iterate over the XML nodes in the template which was not efficient or succint.

In summary, a freemarker template is likely to be 1/3 of the lines of code as an XSLT template doing the same thing. Because you can use java helpers, you can optimise lookups with hashmaps and sets etc. You end up with better performing templates that are more readable and easier to maintain.

One of the downsides to freemarker's XML support is that it is DOM based. So if you are processing enormous XML documents you will get OutOfMemoryErrors. XSLT on the other hand is SAX based.