# What is the better way/technology to transform XML to XML in Java

Tags: xslt

I require to transform XML to XML using Java.
I googled for that and i found few technologies as below

1. JAXB
2. Apache Cocoon
3. XSLT

Can anyone suggest me the better way/technology from the above list?
Please let me know if is there any other better option available.

Note: Want to avoid writing XSLTs.

Thank You.

Comment: Ankur Raiyani: Don't waste your time with non-XSLT technologies -- XML transformation is done factors of magnitude easier, simpler shorter, extensible and maintainable with XSLT. Read a good book on XSLT and apply the acquired knowledge -- you'll be grateful for this correct decision. Here is a list of resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Answer (score 2):

XSLT was created to transform XML to something, and is excellent at transforming to XML.

- Depending on your requirements, pure XSLT could be enough ;
- if your requirements go beyond native XSLT capabilities, using **Apache Xalan**, you can write your own extension functions in java.

Apache Cocoon is a great piece of software, with capabilities of chaining processing units. But it may be overkill. And in the end, you're likely to have to write XSLT for Cocoon to process.

I'm sorry I have no experience with **JAXP** (neither the **SAX** nor **JDOM** options), and can't provide you with pros or cons towards it… Except one good thing is that it provides a third option: XSLT ;-)

If you really don't want to use XSLT, maybe have a look into **Groovy**, which compiles to java classes, and is said to automagically transform XML to object graph, and object graphs to XML. Have a look at the following threads for a quick overview :

- [Groovy read values from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028342/groovy-read-values-from-xml) (about XML to object)
- [Groovy - XmlNodePrinter prints blank file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977493/groovy-xmlnodeprinter-prints-blank-file) (object to XML)

Last, maybe have a look at this quite similar question (and its answers):

- [What are the different approaches for transforming XML with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463405/what-are-the-different-approaches-for-transforming-xml-with-java)

Answer (score 1):

If you want generic, complex transformations, then XSLT is the way to go - AFAIK it is the most powerful tool for the job.

For many simpler tasks, it may not be necessary. If you are just filling more or less uniform documents, like emails or reports, try using a template framework like [freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/).

I am not familiar with Cocoon and rather unsure how you would use JAXB for XML transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes i have idea about XSLTs and even developed some POCs for this. But its very difficult to write XSLTs. So, i want to avoid to write XSLTs. Yes, i know that JAXB is used to transform XML to Object and vice-verse but what i think i can use it like unmarshell input XML to object then using this object set properties of output object and marsheel output object to get output XML. Is this a good way?

Answer (score 1):

It's true that there is a learning curve associated with XSLT. It's also true that it's the best tool for the job. Bite the bullet and get learning.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that saxon is an excellent xslt processor, capable of xslt 2.0. There is a huge difference between xslt 1.0 and 2.0.
I believe it can also be extended in Java.